# os.walk returns one empty list and then my actual list

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list

I'm working on getting some subdirectories to output while ignoring another. I noticed in the output despite everything else seemingly working correctly, that I have an empty list also being returned.

> /usr/lib/python3.9/os.py(407)_walk()->('/home/presto.../pB/media/370', ['images5', 'images'], **[]**)

'images' is removed later on in the code but that final empty list remains.

> /usr/lib/python3.9/os.py(407)_walk()->('/home/presto.../pB/media/370', ['images5'], **[]**)

```
for root, subdirectories, files, in os.walk(wk):
    for subgals in subdirectories:
        if subgals == primary_gallery:
            subdirectories.remove(subgals)
        else:
            subgal_path.append(os.path.join(root, subgals))
    for file in sorted(files):
        raw_subgal_file_paths.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    for x in raw_subgal_file_paths:

        split_root = raw_prim_path_length - len(x)
        compiled_subgal_file_paths.append(x[split_root:])
    print(compiled_subgal_file_paths)
```

The final output looks like this.

```
[]
['/images5/10.gif', '/images5/11.gif', '/images5/20.gif', '/images5/21.gif']
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Apparently, one of the directories that `walk()` is visiting contains only subdirectories, not any files - so the `files` value you receive is an empty list.  This is perfectly normal, why is it a problem for you?

Comment: if you don't want empty list then you should use `if/else` to skip it.

Comment: @jasonharper I spent some time messing around to see how this would affect my code overall and I figured out it doesn't. I thought maybe once it got rendered to html there would be problems but nah. Originally I just thought I was doing something incorrectly but I guess this is just the case with os.walk, thank you for your assistance.